# One-to-many association SELECT records WHERE two or more conditions

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

`person`

```
+-----+------------+---------------+
| id  | name       | address       |
+-----+------------+---------------+
| 1   | John Smith | 123 North St. |
| 2   | Joe Dirt   | 456 South St. |
+-----+------------+---------------+
```

`person_fields`

```
+-----+------------+-----------+-------+
| id  | type       | person_id | value |
+-----+------------+-----------+-------+
| 1   | isHappy    | 1         | 1     |
| 2   | hasFriends | 1         | 1     |
| 3   | hasFriends | 2         | 1     |
```

I want to select all the people from `person` for whom `isHappy` AND `hasFriends` is TRUE. Here's what I have tried:

```
SELECT person.*
    FROM person
      INNER JOIN person_fields
        ON person.id = person_fields.person_id
    WHERE
      (person_fields.type = 'isHappy' AND person_fields.value IS TRUE)
      AND
      (person_fields.type = 'hasFriends' AND person_fields.value IS TRUE)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work because you can't have a single record in `person_fields` that has `type = 'isHappy'` AND `type = 'hasFriends'`. I can't `OR` these two conditions because that would return both John Smith and Joe Dirt, but I only want John Smith because he is the only one who is happy and has friends at the same time.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard solution looks like this:

```
SELECT person_id 
  FROM person_fields 
 WHERE type IN ('ishappy','hasfriends') 
 GROUP 
    BY person_id 
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2;
```

...where '2' is equal to the number of arguments in IN()

Note that this assumes that (person_id,type) is UNIQUE

Comment: I suppose I should have been more explicit in this, but I need to `SELECT * FROM person`. This only gives me the `person_id`.

Comment: Luckily, I'm sure you have the competency to figure that bit out for yourself!

Comment: For sure! Some of the other answers run faster, but this is another option that could work.

Comment: Hmm, imagine if you had five or six criteria. All those joins would get kind of tedious, right? But whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Agreed. That is one thing that I had mentioned to @danblack earlier. However, I am building these join clauses in javascript using Sequelize ORM, so it's really not a problem.

Comment: I still think the above scales better, and should be blisteringly quick on an indexed table

Comment: You may be right, but it doesn't play nice with Sequelize. That being said, it may be the perfect solution for someone else (or even me) in the future.

Comment: Okay, after making some other changes to my query, it turns out this one works a little nicer. I ended up going with a raw query in Sequelize, and so this is now an option. Thanks!

Comment: I would point out the above solution doesn't work on the problem as stated as it fails to check the  `value` column. Some evil person could set one of the values to false/0 and ruin your whole day. Needs an `AND value IS TRUE` in the where clause

Comment: Also `isHappy` and `hasFriends` may be case sensitive strings, although an enumerated value would probably be better.

Comment: @vogomatix pedantry will get you everywhere ;-)

Answer (score 1):

By joining twice:

```
SELECT person.*
FROM person
INNER JOIN person_fields happy
        ON person.id = happy.person_id AND happy.type='isHappy' AND happy.value
INNER JOIN person_fields friends
        ON person.id = friends.person_id AND friends.type='hasFriends' AND friends.value
```

Comment: I see. That does seem to make sense. The only thing I'm a little iffy about is this: if I wanted to find all people for whom 12 fields in the `person_fields` table were true, I'd have to join 12 times?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right! I'll test this tomorrow probably and then mark it as the answer. Long term, I'll probably need to rethink the structure. Thanks!

Comment: more columns to the person table is the easiest way. If you semi-frequently change columns maybe [dynamic columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dynamic-columns). Indexing helps, but you need to know which queries are getting used.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted but this totally works. I suppose it's not quite as readable as the answer by @vogomatix.

Comment: I upvoted :) I didn't even notice it was there when I posted my similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can join `person_fields` in twice, once for `isHappy` and once for`hasFriends`.

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM person p 
INNER JOIN person_fields f1 ON p.id = f1.person_id
INNER JOIN person_fields f2 ON f1.person_id = f2.person_id 
WHERE f1.type = 'isHappy' AND f2.type = 'hasFriends'
```

I'm not sure where the `value` field comes into this but you can throw an extra condition OR two in if you need it

```
AND f1.value = 1 AND f2.value = 1
```

Comment: Both this and the answer by @danblack execute in about the same time, and are the fastest of all the answers. This one is a little more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you always know how many conditions you want to check for, and you always want to only return the `person` records who have all conditions, then you can use a sub-query and modify the HAVING clause to select the maximum number of `type` from `person_fields`:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.name,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pf.type) FROM person_fields AS pf WHERE pf.person_id = p.id and pf.value = true) AS types
FROM
  person AS p
HAVING types = 2
```

Result:

```
id  name       types
1   John Smith 2
```

Comment: What did I miss?

Comment: I'm not sure what you missed either... I like this technique. Unfortunately, I'm using Sequelize ORM and while you can use a HAVING clause with it, my actually query is quite complex and won't allow for this option.